# can't get database to connect during magento installation - using wizard

Tags: magento, installation, database-connection

I’m trying to install magento on my live web server , I’ve checked the server with magento-check.php and thats fine.

I’ve set up a mysql db with the user name and password the of the mysql server

I’ve entered this into the host* along with the username and password into the installation wizard but it will not connect. ?

Can anybody help me with this I know it seems so simple ??

Comment: What's the error that magento is showing??

Comment: This is impossible to answer without more detail. What error comes up? Can you connect to the database using a client tool like [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com)? Is the mySQL server running locally or remotely?

Comment: Vijay thanks for helping and sorry for the delay in replying !

Comment: I can connect to the database ok but cant get magento to connect to it during the instalation rutine , i think i may have worked out why , i'm trying to instal it on my remote server but they only support  MyISAM engine not InnoDB which is what i need for magento ? I'm going to find a hosting company that support InnoDB and try installing again , will post back on the the site with and update. thanks for your help

Comment: I have now installed magento on a server that supports InnoDB, All is well ! used 1and1.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the server i was trying to install magento onto did not support mysql InnoDB - only MyISAM , Magento uses the InnoDB engine. I have now installed several versions of Magento on 1and1 servers.